# Reading data from file and converting

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I pulled the following values from a .txt file via file.read( )- I am trying to figure out a good way to dump all this into a nice data structure (list/dict). Help please?

```
Number=0001, Phone= 4-567-89883, Name =Jason Bates
Number=0005, Phone= 4-002-84764, Name =Damon Bates
```

and so fort and so on....Thoughts?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? That will be important to figuring out what data structure would be best.

Comment: Just want to display in a nice data structure. For e.g. something I can do sort later on if I need to. Maybe a table that has the columns - Number, Phone, Name....and all the data beneath it.

Comment: What does the data file look like?

Comment: For general use you could just use a python `class` with a `__str__(self)` (toString) method, based on your comment above

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list for each person and a dictionary to fetch specific fields.

```
# f is your file object.
people = []
for line in f.readlines():
    d = {}
    for column in line.split(","):
        key, value = column.strip().split("=")
        d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    people.append(d)
```

This creates the following list:

```
[{'Phone': '4-567-89883', 'Number': '0001', 'Name': 'Jason Bates'}, {'Phone': '4-002-84764', 'Number': '0005', 'Name': 'Damon Bates'}]
```

And you access the data like this: `people[id][field]`.

```
print(people[0]["Name"])
print(people[0]["Phone"])
print(people[1]["Name"])
print(people[1]["Phone"])
```

The output:

```
Jason Bates
4-567-89883
Damon Bates
4-002-84764
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### [Numpy's genfromtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) method:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
your_data = genfromtxt('example_1.csv', delimiter=',')
```

### Using [pandas to parse CSV](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) files:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv('example_1.csv')
print d
```